# Trying to follow tutorial simple modal and jquery cookies, doesnt work

Tags: jquery, cookies, simplemodal

I am trying to do newsletter subscription pop up using this tutorial
http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/jquery-newsletter-subscription-popup/Jason_Gilmore01192011.php3?page=2

I set up simplemodal succesfully and if I put $("#basic-modal-content").modal(); script at the end of page everything works perfectly.
Now as per tutorial I need to set up jquery cookies plugin.
I loaded the plugin and replaced jquery.cookie.js code with:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

      if ($.cookie("newsletter") != 1) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
          onClose: function() { 
            $.cookie("newsletter", "1", { expires: 7 }); 
            $.modal.close(); 
          }
        });
      }

    });
```

and nothing happens. so can anybody help me with this as I am very unfamiliar with coding :(
p.s. author of tutorial tells about "Additionally, when using modal dialogs for features such as a newsletter subscription prompt, consider setting a different cookie following the window's closure which sets a cookie which never expires, just to make sure the user doesn't attempt to again subscribe to the newsletter." It is nice feature and I would like to have it so maybe any help with that too.

Comment: most likely *"I loaded the plugin and **replaced jquery.cookie.js code with**"* resulted in this error occuring: `object function... has no method 'cookie'`

Comment: I am sorry, but could you explain it little more?

Comment: The `$` is a shortcut for the jQuery function, however, it's not specific to jQuery. The error `object function... has no method 'cookie'` simply means the object `$` has no method named `cookie`. Remember you access an objects methods and properties through dot notation in Javascript `object.method` or `object.property`.